# Kafka Node: How to unregister handlers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent `EventEmitter`-style `.off()` method on Kafka Node objects -- consumers, producers, etc seem to have no way of removing old event handlers. Do I have to dispose of these objects and get new ones to remove old event handlers?